# Get count of rows where date is less than today

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have done the following to get a list of count for today having a date less than today.  I have done the following code:

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN (EXPIRYDAYE>= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) > 1 
                then 1 
                else 0 
           end)
from bottles;
```

However, I am getting this as error:

> Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Note that I need to do the count that way.  So please help me on the syntax in this way of doing the count.  Thanks

Comment: select count(*) from tablename where date < today

Comment: Because your `WHEN` doesn't make sense. What does `(EXPIRYDAYE>= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) > 1 ` mean? You've got 2 boolean operators there, but no `AND`/`OR` operator. SQL Server doesn't support multiple boolean operators in the same expression. For example `WHERE Col1 > Col2 < Col3` isn't allowed. It would have to be written as `WHERE Col1 > Col2 AND Col2 < Col3`.

Comment: is this part of some larger query?  You might just be able to do SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM YourTable WHERE CAST(EXPIRYDATE AS DATE) < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to try like below

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN EXPIRYDAYE< CONVERT(date, GETDATE())  then 1 else 0 end)
```

In your sql query case when statement is wrong

```
 CASE WHEN (EXPIRYDAYE>= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) > 1 -- here last >1 is illogical
```

Comment: Abadn Tuhin:  I am not getting any syntax error now but when the date is less than today I am still getting the sum as 0.  I forgot to mention that the EXPIRYDATE is of type datetime.  Any help pls?

Comment: @tabby plz https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp check this page for basic case when

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN EXPIRYDAYE< CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
            THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END)
```

You don't need the > symbol before the 1

Answer (score 1):

Following simple query should work for your case. You don't need `CASE WHEN` for this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE EXPIRYDAYE < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

> Note that I need to do the count that way. So please help me on the
>   syntax in this way of doing the count.

I am not sure why you want to do it in a specific way whereas more efficient query is available.